# Unable to skip files using grunt-contrib-clean

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

For the life of me I can't get the clean task to skip certain files.

```
clean: {
  empty_dist: ['./dist/**/*', '!./dist/home/config.js']
}
```

When I run this, my `dist/` dir gets completely emptied, including `dist/home/config.js` which I wanted to skip.

I am running it with `grunt clean:empty_dist` using version `^0.5.0`

[The docs are here.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean)

Also, as an aside, what is the difference between `'**/*'` and `'*'`

Comment: SO isn't a discussion forum where wit is appropriate in thread titles. Please edit your question title to something descriptive.

Comment: I think it might be because dist/home is (itself) being deleted. Perhaps you should change your initial match to `./dist/**/*.js`?

Comment: @brianvaughn is on top of it, I had to '!./dist/home'! Thanks yo.

Comment: Glad it helped! Going to move this down into an answer then so others can more easily find it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `dist/home` is (itself) being deleted. Perhaps you should change your initial match to `./dist/**/*.js` (or escape `!./dist/home`).